# Plotting Webscraped data onto matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, pdf, web-scraping, automation

I recently managed to collect tabular data from a PDF file using camelot in python. By collect I mean print it out on the terminal, Now i would like to find a way to automate the results into a bar graph diagram on matplotlib. how would i do that? Here's my code for extracting the tabular data from the pdf:

```
import camelot 

tables = camelot.read_pdf("data_table.pdf", pages='2')

print(tables[0].df)
```

Here's an image of the table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzFqu.png)

Which then prints out a large table in my terminal:

```
                                                    0          1       2    3     4
0   Country \nCase definition \nCumulative cases \...
1                                              Guinea  Confirmed    2727  156  1683
2                                                       Probable     374    *   374
3                                                      Suspected       7    *     ‡
4                                                          Total    3108  156  2057
5                                           Liberia**  Confirmed    3149   11     ‡
6                                                       Probable    1876    *     ‡
7                                                      Suspected    3982    *     ‡
8                                                          Total    9007   11  3900
9                                        Sierra Leone  Confirmed    8212  230  3042
10                                                      Probable     287    *   208
11                                                     Suspected    2604    *   158
12                                                         Total   11103  230  3408
13                                              Total             23 218  397  9365
```

I do have a bit of experience with matplotlib and i know how to plot data manually but not automatically from the pdf. This would save me some time since I'm trying to automate the whole process.

Comment: It would help if you showed us how the data from the table look like.

Comment: right, thanks, just made that edit :)

Comment: I see the output is a Pandas DataFrame, you should look into plotting data from Pandas, I believe it is not that hard, but I have no experience with Pandas myself.

Comment: Thanks so much Papooch, I'll make sure to do that :)